# Why java Map.merge does not pass a supplier?

Tags: java-8

I want in java a method which allows me to modify a value if exist, or insert one if it doesn't. Similar to merge, but:

1. I want to pass a value supplier and not a value, to avoid creating it when not needed
2. In case the value exists, I don't want to reinsert it nor remove it, just access its methods with a container.

I had to write this. The problem with writing it myself is that the version for Concurrent maps is not trivial

```
public static <K, V> V putOrConsume(Map<K, V> map, K key, Supplier<V> ifAbsent, Consumer<V> ifPresent) {
    V val = map.get(key);
    if (val != null) {
      ifPresent.accept(val);
    } else {
      map.put(key, ifAbsent.get());
    }
    return val;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The best "standard" way of achieving it is to use compute():

```
 Map<String, String> map = new HashMap<>();

 BiFunction<String, String, String> convert = (k, v) -> v == null ? "new_" + k : "old_" + v;

 map.compute("x", convert);
 map.compute("x", convert);

 System.out.println(map.get("x")); //prints old_new_x
```

Now, say, you have your Supplier and Consumer and would like to follow DRY principle. Then you could use a simple function combinator:

```
 Map<String, String> map = new HashMap<>();

 Supplier<String> ifAbsent = () ->  "new";
 Consumer<String> ifPresent = System.out::println;

 BiFunction<String, String, String>  putOrConsume = (k, v) -> {
        if (v == null) return ifAbsent.get();
        ifPresent.accept(v);
        return v;
 };
 map.compute("x", putOrConsume); //nothing
 map.compute("x", putOrConsume); //prints "new"
```

Obviously, you could write a combinator function that takes supplier and consumer and returns BiFunction to make the code above even more generic.

The drawback of this proposed approach is in the extra call to map.put() even if you simply consume the value, i.e. it will be slightly slower, by the time of key lookup. The good news are, map implementations will simply replace the value without creating the new node. I.e. no new objects will be created or garbage collected. Most of the time such trade-offs are justified.

`map.compute(...)` and `map.putIfAbsent(...)` are much more powerful than fairly specialized proposed putOrConsume(...). It is so asymmetrical I would actually review the reasons why you need it in the code.

Comment: Most (relevant) `Map` implementation override the default implementation of `compute` in a way that performs a single lookup, if the key exists, in other words, don’t have an “extra call to map.put()”, even for changing values…

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve what you want with [`Map.compute`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Map.html#compute-K-java.util.function.BiFunction-) and a trivial helper method, as well as with the help of a local class to know if your `ifAbsent` supplier has been used:

```
public static <K, V> V putOrConsume(
        Map<K, V> map,
        K key,
        Supplier<V> ifAbsent,
        Consumer<V> ifPresent) {

    class AbsentSupplier implements Supplier<V> {
        boolean used = false;

        public V get() {
            used = true;
            return ifAbsent.get();
        }
    }
    AbsentSupplier absentSupplier = new AbsentSupplier();

    V computed = map.compute(
            key,
            (k, v) -> v == null ?
                    absentSupplier.get() :
                    consumeAndReturn(v, ifPresent));

    return absentSupplier.used ? null : computed;
}

private static <V> V consumeAndReturn(V v, Consumer<V> consumer) {
    consumer.accept(v);
    return v;
}
```

The tricky part is finding whether you have used your `ifAbsent` supplier to return either `null` or the existent, consumed value.

The helper method simply adapts the `ifPresent` consumer so that it behaves like a unary operator that consumes the given value and returns it.

Answer (score 0):

different from others answers, you also using `Map.compute` method and combine `Function`s with interface default methods / static methods to make your code more **readable**. for example:

### Usage

```
//only consuming if value is present
Consumer<V> action = ...;
map.compute(key,ValueMapping.ifPresent(action));

//create value if value is absent
Supplier<V> supplier = ...;
map.compute(key,ValueMapping.ifPresent(action).orElse(supplier));

//map value from key if value is absent
Function<K,V> mapping = ...;
map.compute(key,ValueMapping.ifPresent(action).orElse(mapping));

//orElse supports short-circuit feature
map.compute(key,ValueMapping.ifPresent(action)
                            .orElse(supplier)
                            .orElse(() -> fail("it should not be called "+
                                 "if the value computed by the previous orElse")));

<T> T fail(String message) {
    throw new AssertionError(message); 
}
```

### ValueMapping

```
interface ValueMapping<T, R> extends BiFunction<T, R, R> {
    default ValueMapping<T, R> orElse(Supplier<R> other) {
        return orElse(k -> other.get());
    }

    default ValueMapping<T, R> orElse(Function<T, R> other) {
        return (k, v) -> {
            R result = this.apply(k, v);
            return result!=null ? result : other.apply(k);
        };
    }

    static <T, R> ValueMapping<T, R> ifPresent(Consumer<R> action) {
        return (k, v) -> {
            if (v!=null) {
                action.accept(v);
            }
            return v;
        };
    }
}
```

### Note

I used `Objects.isNull` in `ValueMapping` in previous version. and @Holger point out that is an overusing case, and should replacing it with simpler condition `it != null`.